# C# code works on local build, but not on live production build

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on expanding the search bar function of my website to allow for more dynamic search results. When I test using the debugger on my local machine, using test tags and searches, it works perfectly. However, when I try and build it and publish it to production, it doesn't work. I've reviewed line-by-line, and I can't seem to find what the issue in the code is.

The way that it works is that for files on my server, it looks at the "Categories" and "Tags" values and appends them to a list. For instance, I have a file named "Annual Results". The "Annual Results" file has a category of "Financials" and has the tags "Results;Money;". I also have a file called "SynonymsDictionary", and yes, it is just a thesaurus, at the path `TagSynonynmsPath`. In that file, it contains a list like this:

```
Results: Result;End;Close;
Financials: Finance;Financial;
Money: Moolah;Cash;Dollars;
...
```

```
                Dictionary<string, string> synonymsDictionary = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(".") + urlInfo.TagSynonymsPath));

                /* Declare the tagList list that will store all of our populated tags */
                List<string> tagList = new List<string>();

                /* Add file categories to tagList */
                foreach(string catTag in file.Value["Categories"].Split(';'))
                {
                    tagList.Add(catTag.ToLower().Trim());
                }

                /* Add file tags to tagList */
                foreach(string fileTag in file.Value["Tags"].Split(';'))
                {
                    tagList.Add(fileTag.ToLower().Trim());
                }

                /* Loop through the newly populated category and tag objects to see if there are synonyms */
                for (int i = tagList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    /* Declare & initialize a new string where we can store our synonyms */
                    string synTags = string.Empty;

                    if (synonymsDictionary.TryGetValue(tagList[i], out synTags))
                    {
                        /* If a string of synonyms is found, split the string up into individual objects and add to tagList */
                        foreach(string cleanedTag in synTags.Split(','))
                        {
                            tagList.Add(cleanedTag.ToLower().Trim());
                        }
                    } else {
                        /* If there are no synonyms, test the next object in the list */
                        continue;
                    }                   
                }

                /* Convert our list into a string of tags, delimited with a ", " */
                file.Value["Tags"] = String.Join(", ", tagList.ToArray());
```

The code should first store both our categories and tags in `tagList` so that the list should contain `Financials,Results,Money`. Then it looks at KeyValuePairs in the SynonymsDictionary file and sees that each tag has a synonym so it should result in this:
`Financials,Results,Money,Finance,Financial,Result,End,Close,Moolah,Cash,Dollars`. This results exactly as it should when I test it locally, but when I build and publish the solution on my actual site, it breaks. When I test it locally, there are much fewer synonyms than on the live site. Any ideas why this code isn't running live?

Comment: When you say "it breaks", what exactly do you see? An error message? Wrong answers? The page hangs?

Comment: It crashes the application pool and I have to restart it on IIS.

Comment: Check the event log on the server for information on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Testing against a small dataset locally and then running in production against a big one is always liable to trip you up on problems like out of memory errors and timeouts. We can't tell you what the problem is without an actual error being caught, but you could attack it by running locally with:

- a faithful copy of production data
- enough logging around this section of code that you get useful clues even when the app pool crashes.